# Cross compile Qt source the Angstrom toolchain(any linux supported embedded toolchain would do)

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am new to cross compiling and willing to get started with cross compiling Qt for beagleboard. Can some one give me specific instructions for this or recently tried tutorial. Please do not assume any knowledge on my part so can not handle instructions like "you may have to edit this to your architecture". I have a few important questions.

1. how to build Angstrom tool chain and how to prepare it for cross compiling. (I have tried the anstrom web site and never found such random instrutions in my life).
2. How to cross compile Qt after installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is a little daunting for the first time developer.  I used this blog to give me a start,

http://treyweaver.blogspot.com/2010/10/setting-up-qt-development-environment.html

but like all of the other instructions, sometimes there will be deviations.  It took me a while to sort it all out.  You are going to have to read and study to to this. It is a worthy thing to do however.  As far as Angstom, there are ready made images available.  I started with that.  You should use Ubuntu to do all of your work.  Linux makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks a million of the answer